# Rails Active Record accessing the data problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a users table and a usergroups table and the user_groups_users for the many to many relation.

Now I want to get all user groups in which a user is signed in ...

I tried this:

```
@usergroups = UserGroup.users.where('client_id = ?', @current_client.id).order('name')
```

But then I got this error:

```
undefined method `users' for #<Class:0x0000000fc027b8>
```

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :user_groups


class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

[image]

What i need is something like that:

```
@usergroups = UserGroup.joins(:users).where('user_groups.client_id = ? AND user_groups.user_id = ?', @current_client.id, session[:user_id]).order('name')
```

Comment: can you post the relations definitions from your models please?

Comment: Can you post your associations?

Comment: models with associations added above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this please

```
 @usergroups = UserGroup.joins(:users).where('user_groups.client_id = ?', @current_client.id).order('name')
```

Comment: I've tried this as well but my where was wrong. that looks much better. But each result is printed three times in view why?

Comment: i guess this is related to your many to many assosiation and data. im not sure.. can you do this `UserGroup.joins(:users).where('user_groups.client_id = ?', @current_client.id).order('name').to_sql` to check what is the query generated and check your records accordingly.

Comment: how should I print this? I've added a screenshot of uwser_groups_users above

Comment: open `rails c` in terminal and first find some @current_client eg: `u = User.last` or `u = User.find_by_id 123` and then do this `UserGroup.joins(:users).where('user_groups.client_id = ?', u.id).order('name').to_sql` to check the query. remove to_sql part to see the output in console

Comment: Can I do this also from Controller?

Comment: Okay I figured out some more ... I need something like that to get the result I need.     `@usergroups = UserGroup.joins(:users).where('user_groups.client_id = ? AND user_groups.user_id = ?', @current_client.id, session[:user_id]).order('name')`

Comment: the condition should be `OR` rather `AND`. try this: `@usergroups = UserGroup.joins(:users).where('user_groups.client_id IN  (?)', [@current_client.id, session[:user_id]]).order('name')` im not sure about the syntax so it would be great if you could confirm

Comment: its the same result. And I need a AND .. I have different clients and each client has different users. And I want to display all Groups for a speical user.